# AS400 Macro, input fields count

Tags: macros, ibm-midrange

5250 emulator:

[image: 5250 emulator]

Hello everyone, I want an operator which will count that input fields as it is shown on attached picture. In this case i have 5 input field.

Thanks in advance and best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done!
Download this source: http://www.code400.com/ffd.php

You can comment out the GETKEY section from FFDRPG as you won't need that and it will probably cause it to fall over anyway.

Also, rememember when you use the command, to put the record format name in as well as your display file name - don't just leave *FIRST in there or you'll just get the fields from the first record format in the display file.

**EDIT:**
You'll need to add an extra field to the ListDs data structure:

```
D ListDs          DS                 
D  SfFld                  1     10   
D  SfType                11     11   
D  SfUse                 12     12   
D  BufferOut             13     16B 0
D  FieldLen              21     24B 0
D  Digits                25     28B 0
D  Decimals              29     32B 0
D  FieldDesc             33     82
```

If you add the 3rd field `SfUse`, you can check whether it contains 'I' so you only count Input Capable fields.

Check out the QUSLFLD API https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_i5_54/apis/quslfld.htm if you want to see exactly what information can be retrieved by this API.

The example in the download uses the most basic format FLDL0100 but more information can be retrieved if you ask for format FLDL0200 or FLDL0300 but they will take longer to execute and you shouldn't need the extra info to achieve what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is possible, but you might find some joy with the DSM APIs.

QsnQry5250 has a maximum number of input fields return parameter, but it may just show you the maximum allowed on the display rather than the number you have on your screen.

There's an example here https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_i5_54/apis/dsm1g.htm

And the API documentation here https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/apis/QsnQry5250.htm

Sorry I can't be of more help - I've never used those APIs and can't think of another way to achieve what you're after.

If you tell us the reason you need to know the number of input fields on screen, we may be able to suggest another way to achieve what you want to achieve.

Damian

Comment: Thanks for replay, I'm writing macros for my work. i need to get number of input fields cause, i am using IF, else in my macro. This fields is different on every page of inventory. For example if inputs are 5, I want to [TAB] 5 times.